# Sorting Jquery Tab Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tab panel.

It can add tabs dynamically by clicking the `add tab` button.

A typical use case scenario will be this:

- I have multiple tabs open Tab-1, Tab2, Tab-3, and Tab-4 in the panel
- and remove some of them Tab-2 and Tab-3 from the panel by closing the tabs.

This will leave Tab-1 and Tab-4 in the panel.

Now, if i try to add new tabs, order in which the tabs are is Tab-1, Tab-4, Tab-2, Tab-3.

I want to sort the panel in jquery and make it Tab-1, Tab-2, Tab-3, and Tab-4

Please Help!!

Comment: If my answer below was useful or correct, please accept it so that I can be awarded the points. You accept by clicking on the check mark displayed beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK jQuery UI doesn't provide this natively.

The order of the tabs is defined by their order in the DOM.

Get a plugin that can sort any dom element and use it to sort the tab divs (or LI, or whatever type of element is necessary).

Some quick examples I found are

http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

and of course: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+sort+elements